# JavaScript onKeyUp time delay

Tags: javascript, onkeyup, timedelay

I need some help with a JavaScript function that I call onKeyUp, it is a Ajax function but every time I write any character it calls the function and it slow the page performance and it check every time, it is an user check with the database.

I tried this:

```
 var timer;
 function chk_me(){

   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer=setTimeout(function validate(){...},1000);
}
```

But my validate function have a parameter so I am unable to pass it, I call the function like this:

```
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="required" onKeyUp="chk_me();" minlegth="4" value=/>
```

Is it right? What should I do?

It is my first question and I hope that you all understand it

Thanks,
Alberto

Thank you all, since I am new I cant do it in a different answer so I edited my question with the solution.
I find this: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/451142-need-advice-acting-only-last-onkeyup-event-series and use the last answer method and add it some code, I leave you the code, like it say it isnt the best way but works so if you have some other way I will appreciate it and use it here it is:

```
var keyCount = 0;
var timeoutCount = 0;

function handleKeyUp() // keyup handler
{
keyCount++;
setTimeout("compareCounts()", 500);
}

function compareCounts()
{
var usuario = document.profileForm.usuario.value;
timeoutCount++;
if (keyCount == timeoutCount)
{
xajax_checaUsuario(usuario);
}
}
```

So I take the var in that way any suggestions to make it better?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'slow the page performance?' What exactly is the problem? Typing is slow, interacting with the page is slow?

Comment: Well it doesnt slow the performance I miss type, the ajax is slower tha the Javascript so i shows with every key pressed if it is available or no and when you though that it is available it can shows you that it isnt available @mrtsherman thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .keyup() delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)

Comment: You're looking for a "debouncer". This has been answered many times on SO in various contexts. Here's an example I gave a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041548/preventing-a-callback-from-executing-until-input-stops/5044395#5044395

Comment: I cant use jQuery thats my main problem, I know that with it all the things become easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't pass `validate` directly to `setTimeout`, but rather call it from within an anonymous function:

```
var timer;
function chk_me(arg) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        validate(arg);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood that at first but then I use it and when perfect, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
var timer;
 function chk_me(myparam){

   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer=setTimeout(function validate(){...},1000);
}
```

In javascript you can access any variables in the scope in which the function is defined.  And below is how you use it.

```
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="required" onKeyUp="chk_me('stringval');" minlegth="4" value=/>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it takes like different var each myparam

Comment: I have find the solution, what I do is this: `var keyCount = 0; var timeoutCount = 0; function handleKeyUp() // keyup handler { keyCount++; setTimeout("compareCounts()", 500); } function compareCounts() { var user = document.profileForm.usuario.value; timeoutCount++; if (keyCount == timeoutCount) { //my process } }` So I take the value of that specific field Thanks @Zoidberg anyways, I think that this isnt the best way but this works for me

Comment: @Zoidberg - `setTimeout` can't pass parameters to the function you specify, so the way you did it in your answer won't work. You can pass it a function that in turn calls a second function with parameters: see gilly3's answer.

Comment: @nnnnn Yes, sorry, small typo... I did not meant to put it in the second function's signature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think what you want is to contain your parameter within a closure:

```
var timer;
function chk_me(myparam) {

    clearTimeout(timer);
    var validate = function() {

       //do stuff with myparam
       var foo = myparam;

    }
    timer=setTimeout(validate,1000);
}
```

As before, the timer ensures any previous calls are canceled, unless there's been a 1 second wait, and when you define validate within the scope of chk_me, the local variable myparam will be visible inside it, even when it's handle is passed to setTimeout.