# How to apply a timeout if a function hasn't been called 1 of N records in 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user performs a certain action (typing) I run a function that applies a specific styling to that user in a list of 100s of users. As the user continues to type this function continues to run.

What I would like to do is apply a time out to remove the styling. Meaning if the function hasn't been called in 3 secs, run another command to remove the styling.

Any suggestions on how to create a timeout like this?

Thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041548/preventing-a-callback-from-executing-until-input-stops

Comment: Given your comments under Phil Klein's answer I think you're going to have to show your existing code. How does your code in one browser know when another user _in another browser_ is typing?

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript's `setTimeout()` method to invoke a method to remove the styling after 3 seconds (3000 ms).  See below:

```
var timeout;

function clearStyling() {
    // clear your styling here
};

$("#typingBox").on("keypress", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(clearStyling, 3000);
    // do your styling here ...
});
```

Comment: but it's not one timeout, given N # of users it can be multiple timeouts at the same time?

Comment: So you want to broadcast these events across multiple browsers?  That will require a server-side solution.  What technology are you using?

Comment: @AnApprentice, this is acting per user, since it is running on each user's browser.

Comment: Yes but in one users browser there could be 100+ users each with there own timeout

Comment: @AnApprentice - How does your code in one browser know when another user _in another browser_ is typing?

Answer (score 0):

Need to see some code to be sure, but it seems you could use `setTimeout()` ([see reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)) with each function call, clearing the old timeout with `clearTimeout()` ([see reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout)) at the beginning of the function.

Comment: How can I make the div the reference?

Comment: You're misunderstanding. The word *reference* is a link to the reference manual.