# Using JavaScript to record a time on the client and then how to compare the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply a timeout if a function hasn't been called 1 of N records in 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752575/how-to-apply-a-timeout-if-a-function-hasnt-been-called-1-of-n-records-in-3-seco)

I'm tracking user typing. What I want to do is every time a user types, store the time the even occurred. Then set a timeout that in 3 seconds checks for values that are older than 3 seconds. For any value that is over 3 seconds perform an action.

What I need help with is:

1. Given all the options, the right way to record a time on the client
2. How to compare #1's time against the current time to determine if the time is GTE 3 secs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do this without recording the actual time. You can set a timeout after three seconds. At the same time you can see whether the pressed key is currently in the array.

Untested, but should be something like this.

```
var keypresses = [];

$('#foo').keydown( function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { keypresses.push(e.keyCode); }, 3000);
    for (var i = 0; i < keypresses.length; i++) {
        if (e.keyCode == keypresses[i]) { 
           //repeat key pressed
        }
    }
});
```