# JavaScript Library to Fire Resize/Key Press Events Once?

Tags: javascript, events, shared-libraries

I had found a library a while back that was a copy of a XAML/.NET solution for events that fire multiple times, and I'm hoping that y'all can help me find it.

The problem is that when you capture a window resize event, it fires for every pixel change in width or height. The same is true for key press events; I only want to fire my autocomplete search event after the user has actually finished typing for a while.

So rather than:

```
$(window).keypress(function() { makeAjaxAutocompleteCall() });
```

I know the library supports something like this:

```
$(window).collect("keypress", 250, function() { makeAjaxAutocompleteCall(); });
```

Where the library collects keypress events, and only fires it once per 250ms.

Comment: Thought this might be a duplicate, and it appears this has been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on

Comment: It's also pretty easy to write your own (although I also recommend Underscore): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041548/preventing-a-callback-from-executing-until-input-stops/5044395#5044395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very thorough blog post explaining Debounce and Throttle

http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation

> Both techniques answer the same question "How often a certain function can be called over time?" in different ways:
>
> Debounce: Think of it as "grouping multiple events in one". Imagine that you go home, enter in the elevator, doors are closing... and suddenly your neighbor appears in the hall and tries to jump on the elevator. Be polite! and open the doors for him: you are debouncing the elevator departure. Consider that the same situation can happen again with a third person, and so on... probably delaying the departure several minutes.
>
> Throttle: Think of it as a valve, it regulates the flow of the executions. We can determine the maximum number of times a function can be called in certain time. So in the elevator analogy.. you are polite enough to let people in for 10 secs, but once that delay passes, you must go!